# Does the "chalk code" exist?

Tags: criminology

I came across this image recently, that claims the existence of a code known by criminals. The post does not mention the area where this code is supposedly used, but it can be inferred it pertains to unorganized burglars.

[image: criminal chalk code]

It's easy to think that this code would go out of vogue with the Internet, but even so there's something about the idea I find too romantic to be true. Here's a similar code used in the episode of Mad Men titled [The Hobo Code](http://madmen.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hobo_Code):

[image: mad men hobo code]

There are many more images like this found on the web. I mentioned I find the idea too romantic to be true, here's why:

- The code is supposed to be known by a certain class (caste?) of people, not shared between friends. "Doing a solid" to unknown hobos or criminals, if such a person oneself, seems awfully well-intended, seeing that there's nothing to be gained by it.
- The code must be secret to have the intended effects. It is very easy to leak.
- Once leaked, it could be gamed by the police or anyone else. Even "legitimate" code consumers can set up traps for their fellow hobos or brothers-in-crime. Thus, people would learn not to rely on it that much.

I will allow that it's possible for such a code to have existed at some point, before being written off as a Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup>.

So, the question: Has there ever been any evidence of symbols marking property, that is known to describe the property's owners or content, intended to be used by criminals?